# POWERSHELL searching for path to files using WHERE command

Tags: powershell, where-clause

I have problem with using where command. I have to search for specific exe file inside C:\Program Files and output path of it.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` will allow you to find files under a folder (this has some very basic filter functionality).  `Where-Object` will allow you to then apply a filter to the results (as complex as you like; e.g. using `$_.FullName` to get the full path to the file / `Get-Content` to read the file's contents.

Comment: Please can you provide more info on what you're trying to do and what you've tried already so we can help you further.

Comment: ps. Typing `Get-Help Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Help Where-Object` (you see the pattern) will allow you to learn more about these commands within PowerShell itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that does something along the lines you're after:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:ProgramFiles -Recurse -Filter '*.exe' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.FullName -like '*git*'} | Select-Object FullName
```

- `Get-ChildItem` lists all files & folders under the given path
- `-Path $env:ProgramFiles` sends the value from the environment variable "ProgramFiles" (i.e. the path to the program files directory) to the Path argument of `Get-ChildItem`
- `-Recurse` says to include subfolders (all the way down).
- `-Filter '*.exe'` says to only return files with the .exe extension.
- `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` says "if some issue occurs (e.g. you don't have access to a folder) don't throw up error messages; just carry on".
- `|` is a pipeline character / says to send each output from the current command to the pipeline input of the next command.  I.e. in this case `Get-ChildItem` is returning a bunch of `FileSystemInfo` objects, which get passed one by one to `Where-Object` for filtering.
- `Where-Object` evaluates a boolean expression; anything that evaluates to `true` goes on through the pipeline; anything resulting in `false` gets blocked/ignored by all further operations.
- `{$_.FullName -like '*git*'}` is the condition to evaluate.  `$_` is the current pipeline variable; i.e. each of the FileSystemInfo objects passed from the `Get-ChildItem` command's output.  The `FullName` is the full path to the file/folder being represented (e.g. `"c:\program files\something\somethingelse\file.exe"`.  `-like '*git*'` says "return any values where the full path contains the text `git` within the path (i.e. `*` being wildcard characters.
- `| Select-Object FullName` then takes the results that are passed on by the `Where-Object` (i.e. those which matched the condition), and returns the single property, `FullName` from those objects; so you get a list of the exes' paths, rather than all of the properties describing them from the FileSystemInfo objects.

Full PowerShell documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/

For help on any specific command, type `Get-Help command`, e.g. `Get-Help Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Especially detailed description of commands. I've been trying to figure this out for hours using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/ , your post clarifies everything.

Comment: No worries / good luck.  FYI: I originally taught myself PS using this book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Learn-Windows-PowerShell-Month-Lunches/dp/1617294160